# Adding external background image dynamically Angular 2 sanitizer

Tags: angular, angular-dom-sanitizer

I'm trying to add a background image within an ngFor loop

After getting warnings

```
WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value url…
```

I looked into using the DomSanitizer, but I am still having trouble getting it to work, either I see no style attached or

```
SafeValue must use [property]=binding
```

this is how I'm declaring the url variable

```
res.map(items=>{

let url = "https://img.youtube.com/vi/"+ items.vidUrl + "/0.jpg";

items.vidUrl =  this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle("'background-image': 'url("+url+")'")
         });

this.blogs = res;
```

When logged, it shows that items.vidUrl is updated correctly

And the HTML

```
<div class="col-4 card" *ngFor="let blog of blogs">
<div class="bg-cover"  [ngStyle]="blog?.vidUrl" ></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Got it working by changing

```
items.vidUrl =  this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle("'background-image': 'url("+url+")'")
         });
```

to

```
items.vidUrl =  this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle("url("+url+")")
         });
```

and in the HTML

```
<div class="bg-cover"  [style.background-image]="blog?.vidUrl" ></div>
```

Comment: It should also work with `ngStyle`, you need to do this: 
`items.vidUrl =  this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle("{'background-image': 'url("+url+")'}")`

Comment: really thanx, i searched a lot for this (simple) working answer